# Is it ok to nest REST resources in "directories" that indicate the resources are of a similar type, as opposed to indicating a belongs-to hierarchy?

Tags: rest, restful-url, api-design

It's common to nest resources in a RESTful API.  For example, to retrieve the employees in company having ID=5:

```
GET /companies/5/employees
```

Is it also generally acceptable in a REST design to put resources in a common "directory" where they don't really belong-to a common parent resource instance?  This is more of a "is-a" relationship, where I think the typical nested structure has the nested resources in a "belongs-to" relationship.

For example, is it acceptable to group two different resources (internal agents, external agents) like follows?  In this case the `agents` part of the path is a category that describes its descendants but isn't really a parent resource.

```
GET /agents/internal
GET /agents/external
```

There are no plans to add any resources using the `/agents` path; it is solely for grouping purposes.

Or is that to be avoided for something like this?

```
GET /internal-agents
GET /external-agents
```

I feel like the second option is more correct, but there is an aesthetic to the first option that that I like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are best practices for REST nested resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources)

Comment: @lorefnon I saw that question but do not think it is similar.  I'm not asking if I should have multiple URLs for the same resource (top level vs nested inside its parent) or which of the two is preferable.  My question is whether it's acceptable to nest children of "is-a" relationships where they do not belong to a common parent resource.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have some `agents` which can be `internal` or `external`:

- /agents/internal is a terrible idea breaking URL consistency
- /internal-agents is a valid idea but beware of drawbacks
- A filter could be better for this use case: GET /agents?status=internal

**/agents/internal is a terrible idea breaking URL consistency**

Having /agents/internal is a terrible idea, it MUST not be used as it will lead to inconsistent URLs in your API which will not be easily understand by humans but also programs.

- The best pattern for REST URL (exluding domain and versioning matters) is this one: `/resources/{resouce id}/sub-resources/{sub-resource id}/`/ No more than 2 levels should be allowed.
  Your first example `/companies/5/employees` is a perfect good example.
- Adding a `/agents/internal` URL will make your API's URLs inconsistent and difficult to understand for humans but also programs. You can end having `GET /agents/2` which return agent with id 2 and also `GET /agents/internal` which return a list of internal agents. Same URL structure but different meanings.

Using a consistent structure for URL helps to understand the semantic without even knowing what an API does.

**/internal-agents is a valid idea but beware of drawbacks**

Your idea of having two specific resources `internal-agents` and `external-agents` is valid.
But it can have some drawbacks depending on the exact use case:

- if you add more *status*, like `partner` for example, you'll have to add a new resource `partner-agents`
- if a consumer want to retrieve both type it'll have to make to calls or you'll have to create a `/agents` resource

**A filter could be better for this use case: GET /agents?status=internal**

A third idea would be to consider internal and external as filter on some status on `/agents` resource.

- `GET /agents` returns all agents (internal + external)
- `GET /agents/2` returns agent with id 2
- `GET /agents?status=internal` returns agents with internal status
- `GET /agents?status=external` returns agents with external status

And if you add a new status like `partner`:

- `GET /agents` returns all agents (internal + external + new partner status)
- `GET /agents/2` still returns agent with id 2
- `GET /agents?status=internal` still returns agents with internal status
- `GET /agents?status=external` still returns agents with external status
- `GET /agents?status=partner` returns agents with new partner status
- `GET /agents?status=internal,partner` returns agents with internal or partner status

*Choosing between filter and specific resources is only a metter of context.
The only thing to keep in mind is to ensure URLs consistency.*