# ExpressJS - RESTful route design for nested/linked resources

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, api-design

It's a general design question about the design of RESTful routes for related/nested resources at the example of ExpressJS with MongoDB. **In summary, how should I design such nested/linked routes?**

About my application/scenario: I've a RESTful service implemented with *NodeJS/ExpressJS* and *MongoDB*. I've two different related models `Category` and `Article`.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const article = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: {

        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {

        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {

        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: true
    }
});

const category = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {

        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

I found two ways to design the relation ship respectively the routes:

### Relationship oriented

This means nested paths are used and the relationship is straight forward `/api/categories/:category/articles/:article`.

The **advantage** is that's super easy to set the article's category because it's possible to preload it by the **identifier path param (:category)** with express middleware.

```
router.post('/', (request, response, next) => {

    let article = new Article(request.body);

    article.category = request.category; // Preloaded category

    ...
});
```

The **disadvantage** is that's really hard to get all articles by oen specific user because with that design you get only all articles for one category. For Example `/api/categories/1/articles` you get only articles for the first category so if you filter with queries for examle `?user=5` you will find only the articles of user 5 for category 1 but **not all** of user 5's articles.

### Accessibility oriented

This means no deep nested routes and separate "endpoint's" for each resource `/api/categories/:category` **AND** `/api/articles/:article`.

The advantage is that's now super easy to filter by the highly diverse properties and condiftions like `?user=5` or `?title=Works`.

A big disadvantage is now that I can't just use the path params identifier for a category because it doesn't exist. The means the user must specify inside of the request body the category. Are there best practices to implement this?

**Which design would you prefer and are there any best practices for dealing with the disadvantage?**

### EDIT

I forgot the specify that I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177431/restful-api-routes-design-nested-vs-non-nested) but it doesn't seem to deal with the mentioned disadvantages. I'm highly interested in approachs to deal with them.

Comment: Take in mind that using something like /path/category/article would led you to broken links every time an article happen to change its category.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly, you can consider the following routes:

- `/categories`: List all categories
- `/categories/:categoryId`: If you decide to make the list of categories scanty, this may provide extra details about **one** category
- `/categories/:categoryId/users` All users with the given category
- `/categories/:categoryId/users?gender=M` All male users within the given category
- `/articles` List all articles
- `/articles/:articleId` List more details about the article ID

Have a look at [Resource Naming here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

The idea is
- If you want more details, e.g. `/categories/:categoryId` and I want just users, I could define the route as `categories/:categoryId?select=users`

> Please note that these are just recommendations to improving your code. If after exhausting all options, you cannot adhere to the stated recommendation, I advice you describe the anomaly in detail in a comment form and proceed.