# Django REST Framework nested routes without PK

Tags: python, django, routes, django-rest-framework, nested-routes

I want to implement routes like this:

```
/items - list of all items.
/items/types - list of all item types
```

I was looking at drf-nester-routs, but nested urls expect {pk} to be passed. Is there any good way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need `pk`, then your route should be `/types` not `/items/types`

You may need to take a look at this SO question about REST nested resources:

[What are best practices for REST nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources)

Comment: Right now it is implemented in this way. But I think it's more logical to make types sub-url of items because they are types of items and nothing else.

Comment: If they are types of items (sub-resources of items) that means you need to add `pk`. If I understand well what you need is `/types` not `/items/<pk>/types`

Answer (score 1):

With ID `/items/1/types` would mean something like "display all types belonging to the item with id 1". Whereas `/items/types` doesn't really make sense because resource types can't belong to all item resources.

However, you could implement it, as a custom action for your ViewSet using `@list_route` decorator, e.g.

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    @list_route()
    def types(self, request):
        return Response(some_way_to_list_types())
    ...
```

It's probably not a RESTful way though.

[Docs on custom ViewSet actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)