# MVC + REST + nested resources + single page app

Tags: php, laravel, rest, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm a novice, but struggling hard to implement this interactive application I'm working on "the right way" or at least a good way in terms of scalability, maintainability, modularity,  development speed  and tool independence. That's why I chose the REST design guides and a framework which implements MVC.

However I can't get my head around where to put what in the following situation and any input or reading material  from a more experienced developer in this techniques would be greatly appreciated :

I'm developing a single page web app which creates a resource that has several nested resources within. In the create methods and alike, I need to call the create methods from the nested resources. Right now every GET request is responded with a JSON, which the front end then parses, shows and add dynamically to the page accordingly. The question is : where should this create and store methods  from nested resources be, in the controller or in the model?

Currently, my approach is : since the controller function is to handle user input, interact with model and return the view accordingly, the nested store methods are in the model since they're not created independently, their create methods are in the controller since  they're requested from ajax calls, but this isn't nested, and so on. I'm worried that this is too mixed up and not general.

Am I ok ? Am I mixed up? I don't wanna make a mess for my coworkers to understand. Theory becomes tricky when applied..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm gonna have a go at this. I am myself still learning about this as well, so if any information is wrong, please correct me.*

In terms of scalability, you should always be able to create any model independently, even though at this point it appears not strictly necessary. The REST paradigm stands for exactly this: Each model (a.k.a. resource) has its own (sub)set of [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) endpoints, which a client application can use to perform any action, on any composition of data (compositions in which elementary entities are mostly the models you specify).

Furthermore, a model should be concerned with its own data only, and that data is typically found in a single table (in the case of relational datastores). In many cases models specify facilities to read related resources, so that this data can be included when requested. That might look like the line below, and the response is ideally fully compliant with the [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/):

`GET //api/my-resources/1?include=related-resource`

However, a model should never create (`POST`), update (`PUT`) or delete (`DELETE`) these relations, not at all without explicit instructions to do so.

If you have a procedure where a model and its nested models (I assume related models) are to be created in a *single go*, an extra endpoint can be created for this action. You'd have to come up with a **sensible name** for that set of resources, and use that throughout your application's HTTP/support layer.For instance, for creation of such a set, the request might be:

`POST //api/sensible-name { your: 'data' }`

Keep the `{ your: 'data' }` 
part as close to a typical JSON API format as possible, preferably fully compliant. Then, in your back-end (I suppose Laravel, inn your case) you'd want to create a [factory implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that might be called `<SensibleName>Factory` that takes care of figuring out how to map the posted data to different models, and how their relations should be specified. Under the hood, this factory just uses the model classes' creation facilities to get you where you want to go.

When you would instead automate this process in your model it would be impossible to create the resources independently.

When you would instead automate this process in any single-resource controller that would be non-compliant with the REST paradigm.

With the factory pattern, you explicitly use that class to perform the higher level action, and none of the above concerns apply, not speaking about whether this approach is in accordance with REST at all.

The key takeaway is that the exact same result must still be achievable by performing multiple requests to single-resource endpoints, and your additional `/api/sensible-name` endpoint just substitutes for the need to call to those multiple endpoints, for the purpose of convenience, when you DO want to create multiple records in a single go.

Note that my statement has little to do with what endpoints to create to fetch nested resources. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources) has some pretty good conversation as to what is acceptable, and how your specific needs might relate to that.

In the end, it's all about what works for you and your application, and REST and the like are just philosophies that propose to you an approach for similar needs in general web development as well as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I like this factory approach much more since it allows for resources to be created independently, and the code is not tied to some place due to a view requirement.
Just to be clear: every model should've its own creation facilites, which are accesible to the factory, and only concerned with their table. Their controllers provide access points for this methods. The factory has access to several model method's and works as a "combined resource" for the single-go operations. Is that ok?
Thanks a lot for your time Jeffrey.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Regardless of whether you provide actual endpoints to perform operations on resources, a scalable application supports implementation of such endpoints at any time from DB to the HTTP layer. Creating a route and controller is then plug-n-play. Good luck, you're welcome.