# Many to Many in RESTFUL API

Tags: rest, many-to-many

For example let's say I have employees and restaurant resources:

```
Employee {ID, Name, Gender, Birthday} exposed to GET\POST\PUT\DELETE
Restaurant {ID, Name, Address, Business_Number} exposed to GET\POST\PUT\DELETE
```

Also, I have many to many resources:

```
Restaurant_Has_Employee {ID, Employee_ID, Restaurant_ID, Employee_Work_In_Restaurant}
```

So the question is, what is the best practise to expose GET\POST\PUT\DELETE to this resource?

Answer (score 2):

I always do this using the following pattern:

`parents/{id}/children`

In your case, if for the sake of the example a given restaurant had the id of 55, then the url `GET restaurants/55/employees` would a return a list of employees that belong to that restaurant, and `POST restaurants/55/employees` would be used for inserting a new employee to that restaurant's record.  `PUT` isn't really relevant here, since it should be used directly on the `employee` endpoint, but `DELETE restaurants/55/employees` could be used to delete all employees belonging to that restaurant.

BTW, this looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources).

Edit: Made path nouns plural

Comment: Call it `restaurants/55/employees` (plural) which is closer to the REST guideline.

Comment: @ygesher so if I call `restaurant/55 GET` it should return also the employees with the `restaurant {ID, Name, Address, Business_Number}`

Comment: No, usually a call like `restaurant/55` just returns the restaurant object. Depending on the relationship between your entities (`restaurant` and `employee`), it may make sense to return an array of employees as a member of the restaurant object (which in turn kind of makes the `restaurant/55/employee` call redundant, but not against the rules)