# Laravel Rest API route best practice

Tags: laravel

let say I've this route

1. `DELETE products/{id}`
2. `DELETE products/{id}/discount`

The first example will call `destroy` function inside `ProductController` but the second example I dont know where to put `deleteDiscount` function whether in `ProductController` or `DiscountController` should I put the second example in `ProductController`? or `DiscountController` in `destroy` function? which is best practice?

Comment: take a look at @Devon answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097352/api-restful-laravel-6-x-best-practice-for-many-to-many-relatioship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to follow something like this in my projects:

// delete a product

`DELETE products/{id}` : `ProductController -> destroy()`

// delete a discount

`DELETE discounts/{id}` : `DiscountController -> destroy()`

// delete all discounts related to a product

`DELETE products/{id}/discount` : `ProductDiscountController -> destroyAll()`

// delete one discount related to a product

`DELETE products/{id}/discount/{discount_id}` : `ProductDiscountController -> destroy()`